# Disable site.mobile.master

Tags: asp.net, webforms, visual-studio-2013

I have created asp.net webforms project and now I would like to disable mobile site.
Tried to rename site.mobile.master but still it getting mobile master somewhere.

Where can I find documentation how that works and remove mobile master totally.

Comment: Did you try just right clicking the file and deleting it? By the way, it's probably from the ASP.NET Friendly URL's NuGet package that's included in the standard template for new Web Forms projects.